# Fatal Error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 53091665 bytes) - Linode server Image Upload

Tags: laravel

I created an API to upload an image to storage. This API works fine when tested on localhost. However, after hosting my application on a Linode sever, when I try to upload an image, I get the error below:

```
"message": "Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 53091665 bytes)",
    "exception": "Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException",
    "file": "/var/www/forms369/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Formatter/LineFormatter.php",
    "line": 103,
    "trace": []
```

I have changed the post_max_size to 512M and upload_max_filesize to 512M and already, my memory_limit=-1 in my php.ini. I have also tried ini_set('memory_limit', '-1') and ini_set('memory_limit', '512M') in my function before the image upload. But I am still getting this error.

This is the function in my controller;

```
public function imageUpload(Request $request)
{

    $this->validate($request, [
        'image' => 'required|mimes:jpeg,jpg,png,gif,psd,tiff'
    ]); 

    $image = $request->file('image');
    $filename = $image->getClientOriginalName();
    $extension = $image->getClientOriginalExtension();

    $current_date_time = Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString(); // Produces something like "2019-03-11 12:25:00"
    $url=$image->getFilename().'_'.$current_date_time.'.'.$extension;
    $upload=Storage::disk('local')->put($url,  File::get($image));

    if($upload)
    {
        return response(['image_name'=>$url]);
    }
    else
    {
        return Reponse::json('Image upload unsuccessful');
    }     

}
```

Comment: Can you also post the upload controller?

Comment: I have edited the question and added the controller.

Comment: After put values in your php.ini has you check values with `phpinfo()` ? Are you r running php mod, cgi or fpm ?